# Convert JSON to CSV - string manipulation (jq, bash, awk, sed, etc.)

Tags: json, csv, export-to-csv, amazon-cognito, jq

I'm in a dire need of help for a script to basically convert JSON text to CSV text in an attempt to copy users from one AWS Cognito userpool to another.

The export JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "Users": [
        {
            "Username": "user.name",
            "Attributes": [
                {
                    "Name": "sub",
                    "Value": "some-value"
                },
                {
                    "Name": "email_verified",
                    "Value": "true"
                },
                {
                    "Name": "custom:jobtitle",
                    "Value": Director"
                },
                {
                    "Name": "custom:user_id",
                    "Value": "38"
                },
                {
                    "Name": "email",
                    "Value": "foo.bar@email.com"
                }
            ],
            "UserCreateDate": some-value,
            "UserLastModifiedDate": some-value,
            "Enabled": some-value,
            "UserStatus": "some-value"
        }
        [more lines down here]... 
    ] }
```

Then the CSV file would contain these lines:

```
,,,,,,,,,foo.bar@email.com,TRUE,,,,,,FALSE,,,Director,,38,FALSE,foo.bar
[more lines down here]...
```

So, the variables would be like this for JSON:

```
{
    "Users": [
        {
            "Username": "%USERNAME%",
            "Attributes": [
                {
                    "Name": "sub",
                    "Value": "some-value"
                },
                {
                    "Name": "email_verified",
                    "Value": "true"
                },
                {
                    "Name": "custom:jobtitle",
                    "Value": %JOB_TITLE%"
                },
                {
                    "Name": "custom:user_id",
                    "Value": "%USER_ID%"
                },
                {
                    "Name": "email",
                    "Value": %EMAIL%"
                }
            ],
            "UserCreateDate": some-value,
            "UserLastModifiedDate": some-value,
            "Enabled": some-value,
            "UserStatus": "some-value"
        }
        ...
    ]
}
```

And like this for CSV:

```
,,,,,,,,,%EMAIL%,TRUE,,,,,,FALSE,,,%JOB_TITLE%,,%USER_ID%,FALSE,%USERNAME%
```

where `%EMAIL%`, `%JOB_TITLE%`, `%USER_ID%`, and `%USERNAME%` are variables, everything else should be just string.

Appreciate your help in advanced guys.

Answer (score 2):

Consider first this filter:

```
.Users[].Attributes
| map(select(.Name | . == "custom:jobtitle" or . == "custom:user_id" or . == "email") )
| from_entries
| [ .email, .["custom:jobtitle"], .["custom:user_id"] ]
| @csv
```

The trick used here is the use of `from_entries` to convert the array of Name/Value pairs to an object with the Names as keys.

Assuming valid JSON input along the lines shown in the Q, invoking jq with the -r option would yield:

```
"foo.bar@email.com","Director","38"
```

Unfortunately the precise requirements are not so clear to me, but you should be able to adapt the above in accordance with your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the script, it's almost there from my goal. Here's what I need as output:

`,,,,,,,,,foo.bar@email.com,TRUE,,,,,,FALSE,,,Director,,38,FALSE,foo.bar`

How can I add fixed string to the output? and how to get the username in the output as well? I'm trying to modify script myself in the meantime right now.